# Angular Material autocomplete clicking on the list not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an autocomplete box that produces the correct autocomplete information and if I press keyboard down and enter it will properly select the choice; however, if I click on the list the choice is not populated in the textbox. Is there something missing that allows the clicking of the list?

Here is the HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
<input type="text" placeholder="Company" matInput [formControl]="companyControl" [matAutocomplete]="autoClient" (focusout)="clearClients()">
<mat-autocomplete #autoClient="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngIf="isLoadingClients" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoadingClients">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredClients" [value]="option.companyName">
    {{option.companyName}}
  </mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Here is the relavent TS:

```
this.companyControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(50),
    tap(() => {
      this.errorMsgClients = "";
      this.filteredClients = [];
      this.isLoadingClients = true;
    }),
    switchMap(value => this.clientService.getFilteredClient(value)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.isLoadingClients = false;
        })
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((data: IClient[]) => {
    if (data) {
      this.errorMsgClients = "";
      this.filteredClients = data.filter(client => { return client.companyName });
    } else {
      this.errorMsgClients = data['Error'];
      this.filteredClients = [];
    }
  });
```

Comment: what you want do when you click on any item you selected

Comment: @harkeshkumar I would like it to populate the formcontrol with the clicked result

Comment: Share the stackblitz link with the same

Comment: @PujanShah I cannot share a stackblitz due to the fact that this is pulling my real production data

Comment: Could you please share the code in a stackblitz link with a mock of data.

Answer (score 1):

***I am not am getting your question correctly or not if am miss understand your please let me know so I can update my question according to that ***

```
<mat-form-field>
<input type="text" placeholder="Company" matInput [formControl]="companyControl" [matAutocomplete]="autoClient" (focusout)="clearClients()">
<mat-autocomplete #autoClient="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='getSelectedValue("$event.option.value)'>
  <mat-option *ngIf="isLoadingClients" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoadingClients">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredClients" [value]="option.companyName">
    {{option.companyName}}
  </mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-autocomplete>





this.companyControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(50),
    tap(() => {
      this.errorMsgClients = "";
      this.filteredClients = [];
      this.isLoadingClients = true;
    }),
    switchMap(value => this.clientService.getFilteredClient(value)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.isLoadingClients = false;
        })
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((data: IClient[]) => {
    if (data) {
      this.errorMsgClients = "";
      this.filteredClients = data.filter(client => { 

                   this.companyControl.patchValue(client.companyName); /// if this not working please try below 
                   return client.companyName 
            });
    } else {
      this.errorMsgClients = data['Error'];
      this.filteredClients = [];
    }
  });
```

> LIke something this

```
getSelectedValue(value:string){
  this.companyControl.patchValue(value);
}
```

Comment: I will start with the second part. I have not been able to get that to work. If i put a console.log in the method it is never actually triggered. I don't know why optionsSelected isn't triggering a method call but it isn't. The first option works but it creates a flutter effect where whatever the first thing returned is gets put in and the option list flashes constantly not allowing more things to be entered.

Comment: Any idea if there is a fix for this?

Comment: sorry i don't get your question at the fix you asking

Comment: OptionSelected currently only works when pressing the enter key not when clicking an option on the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to the **blur event**. Because **blur event** also get called with the **selection**. It can be resolved by using **(mousedown)=$event.preventDefault()** on the **mat-option** that should not trigger a blur event when clicked. For example:

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="optionSelectedEvent($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of list" [value]="option.number" (mousedown)=$event.preventDefault()>
            {{ option.number }} {{ option.date }}
        </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```